# How to reset DIV offsetHeight when contained text font is reduced

Tags: javascript, dom, offsetheight

I have a `<div>` that is used to determine the vertical space required by an arbitrary text string. By default, the height of the `<div>` box grows to accommodate the text, including wrapped lines, etc.

If I increase the font size of the contained text, the `<div>` height will grow nicely as required.

However, not the other direction. If I reduce the font size, the `<div>` offsetHeight maintains a high-water-mark value.

True for Firefox and Chrome at least.

Is there a strategy for coercing the browser to adjust downwards?

Comment: It seems it has a `min-height` property. Try removing it.

Comment: [Seems not to be a problem](http://jsfiddle.net/fn58u/)?